# TeXshop won't compile after any failure to compile due to a coding error on my part, unless I delete the .aux file first

Tags: compiling, texshop, auxiliary-files

If my LaTeX fails to compile because of any error (e.g. if I forget a dollar sign or something around my equations and try to compile) then it won't compile the next time unless I delete the .aux file it creates first. If I click 'go to error' button, it highlights my \begin{document}. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: The aux file is read in early in the compile if it exists. Unfortunately a failed compile can leave the aux file in an bad state that causes an error upon reading. Therefore it must be deleted before recompiling. This doesn’t always happen but it’s good practice.

Comment: If it does this on _every_ error it suggests that you are quitting tex incorrectly (such as killing the process) rather than quitting cleanly with `x` at the error prompt.

Comment: I never had to do this before. It just started happening yesterday.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, David, this works! I didn't know that was a thing.Thanks!